# MSBuild and Web Deployment Project external dependencies

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment-project, wdproj

First time MSBuild/CI setup.  I've got all my class libraries building, but am getting hung up on a web deployment project.  This requires several binaries that are to be copied from a sibling folder.  The folder contains other binaries that I do not want copied; I just want what it needs and nothing more.

The csproj files specify the binaries with a handy "hintpath" so I can point them to the right place.  This doesn't seem to be present in the wdproj.

My preference is not to add them to subversion in the web site's bin directory.

What's the secret sauce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hesitate to answer my own question this way but since nobody else seems to have any ideas... I switched the site being compiled from a Web Site to a Web Application Project.  That's introduced its own problems, but at least now I don't have to keep a bin folder in subversion.